# Beginner's clojure attempt to hackkerrank problem timing out

Tags: clojure

I'm attempting the following problem on hackerrank:

https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/counting-valleys

but unfortunately my following clojure code is timing out on many test cases, and I don't know what makes it so inefficient. Please be lenient. I only have in total 2 hours of total clojure experience.

```
(require '[clojure.string :as str])

; Complete the countingValleys function below.
(defn countingValleys [n s]
    (do 
    (def running 0)
    (defn counter [elem]
    (do
        (cond 
        (= elem "D") (def running (+ running 1))
        (= elem "U")(def running (- running 1))
        )
        running
    )

    )

    (def valley-num 0)

    (defn valley-count [a b]
    (do
        (if (and (= a "U") (= b 0))
        (def valley-num (+ valley-num 1)))
    )
    )

    (def heights (for [elem s] (counter elem)))
    (doseq [[i j] (map vector s heights)]
    (valley-count i j))
    valley-num
    )


)

(def fptr (get (System/getenv) "OUTPUT_PATH"))

(def n (Integer/parseInt (clojure.string/trim (read-line))))

(def s (read-line))

(def result (countingValleys n (str/split s #"")))

(spit fptr (str result "\n") :append true)
```

Dead easy python implementation of the same logic that took 5 minutes and passes all test cases:

```
def countingValleys(n, s):
    list = []
    for i in range(len(s)):
        d = 0
        if s[i] == "D":
            d = 1
        elif s[i] == "U":
            d = -1
        if len(list) == 0:
            list.append(d)
        else:
            list.append(list[-1] + d)
    num = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i] == "U" and list[i] == 0:
            num += 1
    return num
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What do you think could be responsible for this slow time?

Comment: I'm not sure. I basically implemented the same logic in python, and it passed all tests. Perhaps I'm doing something very specific to Clojure that's inefficient.

Comment: You should follow a Clojure tutorial to understand the basics of functional programming, that’ll help you a lot in writing more idiomatic (and so performant) code. In particular, use [`let`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/let) instead of `def` and `defn`.

Comment: This question belongs on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out. The inefficiency was in this line:

```
(doseq [[i j] (map vector s heights)]
    (valley-count i j))
```

Which can be replaced with:

```
(doall (map valley-count s heights))
```

and then all tests pass.

Answer (score 0):

The slowness of your code is the least of its problems. The tools you ought to be employing are

- pure functions,
- the sequence library,
- and, for speed, the prospect of transducers.

I like your underlying algorithm: count the cases where an *up* movement takes you to sea level.

We can express it idiomatically thus:

```
 (defn countingValleys [n s]
  (let [counter {\D 1, \U -1}
        heights (reductions + (map counter s))
        s-heights (map vector s heights)
        valley-num (count (filter #{[\U 0]} s-heights))]
    valley-num))
```

... or, using the `->>` threading macro ...

```
(defn countingValleys [_ s]
  (->> s
       (map {\D 1, \U -1})
       (reductions +)
       (map vector s)
       (filter #{[\U 0]})
       (count)))
```

These are clearer and faster than yours.

---

It seems that you and HackerRank are actually using ClojureScript. Your use of `"U"` as an element of a string  won't work in Clojure proper: you have to use the character `\U`.

Answer (score -1):

```
Those of us who are JavaScript(Node JS) developers, my solution here works perfectly

// Complete the countingValleys function below.
function countingValleys(n, s) {
  const min = 2;
  const max = 1000000;
  let valleys = 0;
  let isInValley;
  s = (typeof s === 'string') ? s.split('') : s;

  if (s.length >= min && s.length <= max &&
    n === parseInt(n, 0) &&
    n >= min &&
    n <= max &&
    n === s.length) {
    s.map(steps => ((steps === "U") ? 1 : -1))
      .reduce((prev, next) => {
        if (prev < 0 && !isInValley) {
          isInValley = true;
        }
        if ((prev + next) === 0 && isInValley) {
          valleys++;
          isInValley = false;
        }

        return prev + next;
      });

  }
  return valleys;

}
```

Comment: Giving out a JavaScript solution when OP is asking for help with Clojure doesn't seem very helpful.